# Configure Jersey MVC to serve Viewable without web.xml

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jax-rs, web.xml, jersey-2.0

The important part is: without web.xml.

I already have a working JAX-RS app running on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 without a web.xml, configured purely by annotations.

The question is, how can I maintain the web.xml-less nirvana and still use Jersey MVC to serve static resources from the resources or webapp directory of my Maven .war project?

I see in many answers how can I do this with web.xml configuration, but nobody mentions how to map resources without the web.xml file.

Currently I have a ui.html file under the resources directory, a JAX-RS Application subclass and a resource class. No web.xml in the project and the following is working well:

```
@Path("/ui")
@GET
public Response ui() {
    String content = "Hello StackOverflow";
    return Response.ok(content).build();
}
```

While this one is failing with the IOException from the resolver:

```
   @Path("/ui")
   @GET
   public Response ui() {
      Viewable viewable = new Viewable("/ui.html");
      return Response.ok(viewable).build();
   }
```

java.io.IOException: The template name, /ui.html, could not be resolved to a fully qualified template name
I also tried to specify it with a relative path, but that didn't work either.

The dependencies I'm using for Jersey are as follows:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

I understand that a proper example project would be the best and willing to provide that if people are having a hard time figuring out what I'm talking about, just let me know.

Comment: What is your application path? If it is "/", then it basically hides any templates and Jersey won't be able to look them up unless you register it as a filter instead of a servlet. Registering it as a filter isn't possible without web.xml.

Comment: I have a 'proper' application path, and the resource classes also have their own defined so that should not be the problem.
I can see now that the question is just not good enough, will create a small, focused example project today evening. Thanks in advance if you have a look at that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Peter Metz, I believe this is possible by using the @WebFilter annotation on a class that extends org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer (Jersey 2.26):-

```
package com.myorg.myapp.config;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;

import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

@WebFilter(value = "/*", initParams = @WebInitParam(name = "javax.ws.rs.Application", value = "com.myorg.myapp.config.JerseyConfig"))
public class JerseyFilter extends ServletContainer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```